# modify promises creation and fetching to detailed profiling of async nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

To profile my app more detailed I need to know which promises not awaited but... js not provide such ability.

In python every time when result of async function is not awaited it prints warring
But how to obtain such result in js?
I concluded to do so I have to know few things:

- how to override promise construction (to add state field which will show is promise awaited and to set timeout to check state)
- what triggered when object **awaited** (to change state)

I figured out via Proxy that when awaiting, object's **then** property is called:

```js
async function test(obj) {
  await obj
}

test(new Proxy(new Object(), {
  get(obj, name) {
    console.log("get " + name)
  }
})
```

But actually, as turned out, it happens only with non-promise objects
So when I tried to do this:

```js
Promise.prototype.then = function() {
  console.log("called then")
}

test(Promise.resolve({}))
```

I got nothing in output.

Same things with **Promise.prototype.constructor** and **Promise.resolve**:

```js
let getOne = async () => 1
getOne()
```

getOne neither call Promise constructor nor Promise.resolve.

So what I'm doing wrong ?

How actually async/await creates promises and fetch value from them under the hood, and how can it be overridden  ?

Comment: What real world problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: When working with node.js, you'll want to look into [async hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html). Do not try to overwrite the promise constructor or methods - it will not work for promises created by `async` functions anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I figured out via Proxy that when awaiting, object's `then` property is called

Indeed, that is correct.

> when I tried to do [...] `test(Promise.resolve({}))` I got nothing in output.

That is because in this code -- contrary to your earlier test with `await` -- you do not execute an `await` or a `then` call here. You just construct a promise, and your proxy object is not trapping the creation of a promise, only the *execution* of the `then` method.

This brings us back to your first bullet point:

> how to override promise construction?

You cannot.

We have access to the `Promise` constructor, but there is no way you can trap its execution. If you would make a proxy for it -- with a `construct` handler -- it would not be called, as the JavaScript engine will still refer to the *original* `Promise` constructor when -- for instance -- an `async` function is executed. So you are without hope here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe overriding is something you want. Usually async is telling node that this function is asynchronious and if you have something in the event loop that is "long" procedure such as querying another API or reading IO then those functions will yield promises. You can also try using the following:

`return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {... do stuff and call resolve() or reject() based on the expected output})`

The returned value will be a promise.
To handle the promise you will need to `await` it.
To get promise from
`let getOne = async () => 1` you will need to make it

`let getOne = async () => return new Promise((resolve, reject) => return resolve(1))`

To obtain the value later you will need to call `await getOne()`

Comment: You can also use getOne().then( data => ...do stuff);
data will containt basically the number one in this case.